# How can I use .d.ts with in local javascript function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wonder how can I use .d.ts file to local javascript files.

I know I can declare module to give a type to third-party libs.

```js
// index.d.ts (wrote on place typeRoots)

declare module "random-joke" {
  const getRandomJoke: () => Promise<any>;
  export { getRandomJoke };
}
```

like this. so I can use this "random-joke" library with type.

but how about this? I am try to import { sum } function in index.ts

```js
// module/utils.js

export function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

export function power(a, b) {
  return a ** b;
}

export function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

```js
import { sum } from "./modules/utils"; 

//'sum' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) 
//Could not find a declaration file for module './modules/utils'.
```

I tried declare module like this. but it doesn't works (It would have been pretty funny if this worked)

[image]

Anyway, I tried everything what I know. But the only thing that worked out was set allowJS:true in tsconfig.json

I know it isn't a right answer. then how can I make typescript get types in d.ts file in fair with javascript functions?

Even a little hint would be of great help. thanks

Comment: Hey, sorry this is unrelated to your questions, but I really want to know which font and color theme you are using. Would appreciate it if you share, thanks!

Comment: @SonNguyen sure. 

theme : "Doki-theme" -> Eva:Rei,
font : D2Coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, now I got how these things work.

just create your d.ts file with prefix of your js file.

in this case, you should make "utils.d.ts"

```js
// module/utils.d.ts

export declare function sum(a: number, b: number): number;
export declare function power(a: number, b: number): number;
export declare function multiply(a: number, b: number): number;
```

then ts will get types by comparing file name.

[image]

as you can see, now you can use your js functions within types.

just be sure add your .d.ts file path in tsconfig.json.

```
{
   //...

    "typeRoots": [
      "./types",
      "./modules" // my d.ts files are in "types" and "modules"
    ] /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */

  //...
```

hope this answer were help.

Comment: How to do it with objects?